# Using a usb digital scale in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a FedEx shipping application and I am trying to get the scale to read either dynamically or when the user ships.  I need help trying to connect and get data from a usb scale in vb.net.  I know how to do it for a serialport but i have no idea for a usb.  How would i go about this?

this is my serialport code that i tried getting the port name to read the usb, but it kept saying "port name does not contain COM/com in it".

```
Private Sub testScale()
        Dim Data As String
        SerialPort1.Close()
        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM1"
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.Odd
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 7
        SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.Two
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write("W" & vbCr)
        Data = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        txtOutput.Text = Data
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Are there drivers involved or an SDK?  A USB port is not that different from a serial port, but you need a way to determine what device you are looking for so you don't have to hard code anything.  A device ID and something using reflection I would guess without seeing any code examples.

Comment: I've only tried adapting serialport for it but it keeps saying "port name doesn't contain COM/com", so i'm not sure how i would force that to read the usb port.  Everything i keep reading on HID says you need a HID.dll to connect to them but can't find one for vb.net.  i've included my serialport code at the top.

Comment: It depends on whether your device emulates a serial port, if so you can just use System.Net.Sockets.Socket class to communicate with it.  Otherwise you'll need the appropriate driver or API/SDK.

Comment: This might be helpful if the device is using a virtual com port. Try looking at _Device Manager>Ports_ (expand the Ports node) to see if a _USB Serial Port_ is listed when the scale is connected. If so, you can see which port number is being used. You can also change it if needed.

Comment: it's listed as an Human interface device.  I'm sure i will need the HID library from what i read everywhere but every link that looks promising to download it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It might be helpful to search the Internet to see if there is some code already out there. What you're trying to do is a bit niche, but as with lots of things, the chances are that someone somewhere has already done this. for example [THIS](http://www.averyweigh-tronix.com/products/industrial-weighing-scales/postal-scales/Postal-Software-Downloads-Drivers/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what i wanted using this site: http://www.bumderland.com/dev/USBHIDScale.html.  Using the HidLibrary.dll and converting the C# code to vb.net.